# running script (r script) remotely to other computer in mac (iMac OSX ) terminal

Tags: r, macos, ssh

I have small example script (`script_p.r`) like the following, which in intend run in terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
sink("output_capture.txt")
mn <- mean(1:10)
# and so on, much longer list of tasks
```

I want to run this script remotely with other iMac host computer (ip address e.g.. not real :  `111.111.111.111`) which allows me to log in and work (e.g., not real. username `user101`, password `p12334`)

Is this way to run this script remotely (say using `ssh`), say from other computer with ip address: `222.222.222.222`  and user name `user102` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put `script_p.r` on the remote machine.

Then either just do:

```
ssh user102@222.222.222.222
user102:-$ ./script_p.r
```

or `ssh user102@222.222.222.222 'script_p.r'`

or put it in a script:
`runremote.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user102@222.222.222.222 'script_p.r'
```

and run locally

```
user101:-$ ./runremote.sh
```

Comment: do you mean "script_p.r" not "script_p.t" ? should run remote.sh need only one comma in script_p.r thanks